# Apache reverse proxy with multiple destinations

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to to set up my Apache2 reverse-proxy so I can have one domain and redirect it to multiple Docker apps running on a different VM with https://apps.mydomain.com/ https://apps.domain.com/app1 etc. but I can't get it to work.

I know the firewall is not the problem as if I access http://IP:PORT the apps are loading normally.

My config looks fine to me but I'm an amateur in this regard, could someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I'm searching for the solution for several days now but still can't get it working.

Apache error log returns just this error:

> [proxy_http:error] [pid 628660] [client 5.X.X.X:60924] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 94.X.X.X
> [proxy:error] [pid 628660] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 94.X.X.X:8585 (*) failed

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName apps.mydomain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html

 ProxyPreserveHost   On
 RewriteEngine       On

 ProxyPass /.well-known !
 RewriteRule         ^/app1/(.*) http://94.X.X.X:8082/app1/$1 [P,L]
 ProxyPassReverse    /app1/      http://94.X.X.X:8082/app1/
 RewriteRule         ^/app2/(.*) http://94.X.X.X:8686/app2/$1 [P,L]
 ProxyPassReverse    /app2/      http://94.X.X.X:8686/app2
 RewriteRule         ^/app3/(.*) http://94.X.X.X:8787/app3/$1 [P,L]
 ProxyPassReverse    /app3/      http://94.X.X.X:8787/app3
 RewriteRule         ^/app4/(.*) http://94.X.X.X:8989/app4/$1 [P,L]
 ProxyPassReverse    /app4/      http://94.X.X.X:8989/app4/
 RewriteRule         ^/(.*)      http://94.X.X.X:8585/$1 [P,L]
 ProxyPassReverse    /           http://94.X.X.X:8585

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/apps-error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/apps-access.log combined

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =apps.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Instead if using RewriteRule's why not just use a bunch of ProxyPass with mirroring ProxypassReverse rules? - ie get rid of the RewireRules?

Comment: I did try something like that, but the problem was when i was going to https://example.com/app1 i got redirected to https://example.com and got 404 page not found.